# How ca I get ID from this json

Tags: marketing-cloud, fuel-sdk

A very basic question, how can I get "ID" value from below json. This json returned when you select data extension from exact target, using FuelSDK php.

```
stdClass Object ( 
    [PartnerKey] => [ObjectID] => [Type] => DataExtensionObject [Properties] => stdClass Object (
        [Property] => Array (
            [0] => stdClass Object ( 
                [Name] => ID [Value] => xxxxxx 
            ) [1] => stdClass Object ( 
                [Name] => Parent Name [Value] => yyyyyyy
            ) [2] => stdClass Object (
                [Name] => Booking Number [Value] => vvvvvvv 
            ) 
        ) 
    ) 
)
```

Comment: $response->results[0]->Properties->Property[0].value;